# Removal of a countable collection of pairwise disjoint closed balls from the plane,and path connectedness

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

Its well known that the removal of countably many points from the euclidean plane doesn't affect path-connectedness.I am interested to know that if I remove a countable collection of pairwise disjoint closed balls from the plane,will it remain path connected or not.Any help would be highly appreciated,thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove the closed balls of radius $0.5$ centered at, say, the even integers on the $x$ axis in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Do you still have path-connectedness?

Comment: @SystematicDisintegration A single example where pathconnectedness is preserved won't solve the general problem

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen That is true. I merely wished to produce a simple example where pathconnectedness holds.